# Triggering function when image is loaded

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am creating an ionic application. In this application, I have an image which I want to resize (itself and the map area associated) when the loading of that image is finished. The problem is I don't know which directive to use to call (it doesn't seems to be [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)).

Example of what I want to do :

```
<div class="ng-scope" ng-controller="ScreenshotCtrl">
  <img
      id="main_img"
      class="rwdimgmap"
      ng-src="img/home.jpg"
      usemap="#map_main_img"
      width="360" height="569"
      ng-directive_I_dont_know_of="theFunctionIWantToCall">
  <map name="map_main_img">
    <area shape="rect" coords="358,567,360,569" alt="Image Map" style="outline:none;" title="Image Map" />
    <area href="#/homemenu"
        shape="poly"
        coords="359,246,282,91,16,220,182,557,356,474"
        style="outline:none;"
        target="_self" />
  </map>
</div>
```

How to do this ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your custom directive like so:

```
myApp.directive('onImageLoad', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            element.addClass('image-not-loaded');

            element.bind('load', function() {
                element.removeClass('image-not-loaded');
                // Your custom code like so
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And use in your HTML:

```
<img src="...." on-image-load />
```